# Text translation issue with Clear Architecture & Nougat

Tags: android, translation, android-7.0-nougat, clean-architecture

Implemented text translation in Nougat and below by referring http://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/

Working perfect till Marshmallow.

In Nougat, messages from app module is working perfect.

Texts from data module is translating in Device language, not in the app language.
eg: Device language is en_US, app language is fr_FR.

Anyone faced this scenario ??